# Trouble with Gate feature with third party user management in Laravel 5.1.26+

Tags: php, laravel, authorization, acl

I am trying to integrate our SSO (Single Sign On solution) to a oldish laravel app and after upgrading to 5.1.26 I want to try the ACL solution but running into an issue. I have added a basic ability to try this out but it doesn't work and I want to help to solve it.

```
<?php
namespace App\Providers;

use Auth;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Gate as GateContract;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot(GateContract $gate){
        $this->registerPolicies($gate);

        $gate->define('create-report', function ($userRoles) {
            return in_array('super_admin', $userRoles);
        });
    }
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

And I try this with

```
if(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate::allows('create-report', $roles)){
    dd("This never happens");
} else {
    dd("This always happen!");
}
```

Do I need to "log my user in"? Since we have our central user mgmt system I never handle any users in the app. I only have a user object (fetched from the sso api) saved in a session variable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes

"The Gate will automatically return false for all abilities when there is not an authenticated user or a specific user has not been specified using the forUser method."

[Laravel - Authorization - Defining Abilities](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authorization#defining-abilities)

Comment: How do I log in a user then?

Comment: well that is a separate question from your posted question. There are different ways to do that.  http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication